# CSS Table cell padding mess up

Tags: html, css

Given this HTML and CSS code:

```css
header,
footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 1024px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

section {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  /* This line is the root of the problem */
  padding: 20px;
}

aside {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #c5c5c5;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<div id="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section>left<br />left<br />left<br />left<br />left<br /></section>
    <aside>right<br />right<br />right<br />right<br />right<br /></aside>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

I have a problem when I add padding on the `section` element (the left element).
It also adds some padding-top on the `aside` element (the right element), which I do not want.

Here is a screenshot WITHOUT padding:

[image]

And here is a screenshot WITH the padding on the left element:

[image]

Any clue on how to get rid of the automatically added padding on the right element?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `padding: 20px` causes that problem
That means you set padding for both of top, left, right and bottom
In table, each cell in row will have the same style
So, to fix that, try this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>PoC</title>
    <!-- Reset CSS by E. Meyer -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/reset.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
     header, footer { text-align: center; background: #fafafa; padding: 20px 0; }

     .wrapper { display: table; width: 1024px; background: blue; margin: 0px auto; }
     table > tr > td:first {
         padding-top: 20px;
     }
     section {
         width: 50%;
         display: table-cell;
         background: #e5e5e5;

         /* This line is the root of the problem */
         //padding-top: 20px;
     }

     aside {
         width: 50%;
         display: table-cell;
         background: #c5c5c5;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>header</header>

    <div id="main">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <section>left<br />left<br />left<br />left<br />left<br /></section>
            <aside>right<br />right<br />right<br />right<br />right<br /></aside>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Actually, I only want the left element to get the padding. Not the right one.

Comment: If "In table, each cell in row will have the same style", why does the right element do not have the padding at its left side of its content? like the other cell, in fact?

Comment: Please see edited answer, I mean "the same style" here is the same height.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `display: table-cell` in your `aside` which aligns it with the `section`.

This means the `display: table-cell` element will take up the same padding as its predecessor which in this case is the `section` element.

Remove `display: table-cell` and add `display: inline-block`, and give `vertical-align: top` to `section`, cause the default `vertical-align` property attributed to an element with `display: inline-block` is `bottom`.

Try the following code:

```css
header,
footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 1024px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

section {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 20px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

aside {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #c5c5c5;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header</header>

<div id="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section>left
      <br />left
      <br />left
      <br />left
      <br />left
      <br />
    </section>
    <aside>right
      <br />right
      <br />right
      <br />right
      <br />right
      <br />
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```